# Workarounds for Mobile Safari (iOS 7.1) Fixed Position Tap Inaccuracy?

Tags: html, css, ios7, mobile-safari

Safari on iOS 7 is exhibiting a bug with a fixed header Nav where the click targets don't seem to map correctly to where the elements are painted.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/lsirivong/full/KrGAJ/)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Scroll the page until Safari's address bar shrinks and bottom toolbar disappears.
2. Tap a button on the bottom row (for example the 'z' button).

   - This should cause the address bar to expand and the bottom toolbar to reappear.
   - Notice also that the button click does not trigger.
3. Now try to tap a button in the top row (for example the '1' button).

   - A button lower than where the tap occurs will activate.

Some ideas I've had for a workaround would require...

- An event that is triggered when the Safari UI state changes. I haven't seen resize or scroll trigger. Is there a mobile safari specific one I may be missing?
- An event that I can trigger that toggles this UI state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your header buttons?

If that works, it's probably due to layer promotion in WebKit. I can add additional info/links if it does.